# .checked = true or setAttribute("checked", "checked") is not appended

Tags: javascript, html

I need to use the CSS "checkbox-hack" for a sliding menu indicator effect and my only approach is to append the input elements by JavaScript. I'm forced to do this via an online tool, MonoSolutions, and I'm limited by a lot of elements and attributes are set automatically outside of my control, otherwise I would have manually added this in the DOM. Anyhow:

This is what I have:

```
window.onload = function AddCheckbox() {
  var listitem = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for(i = 0; i < listitem.length; i++) {
    var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox.type = "radio";
    checkbox.name = "slide-item";
    checkbox.className = "slide-toggle";
    checkbox.id = "menu-item-" + [i+1];
    if(listitem[i].className == " active")
    {
      checkbox.checked = true;
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName("li")[i].appendChild(checkbox);
  }
}
```

Everything in this function works perfectly ***except*** the if-statement to set the checkbox default state to `checked` and I can't figure out why this part is not appended to the checkbox under the "active" li element.

I have tried the alternative `checkbox.setAttribute("checked", "checked");` without luck. I tried another approach with `var activeClass = document.querySelector("li");` and using that with `if(activeClass[i].classList.contains("active"))` but nothing...

As `aria-current="page"` is added by the editor I figured I could also try `if(listitem[i].ariaCurrent == "page")` but that doesn't work either.

Note that I'm in no control how the li class name is set. The online tool sets `<li class tabindex="0">` on non-active menu items (no class name at all, just an empty attribute) and sets `<li class=" active" tabindex="0" aria-current="page">` for the active menu item. For some stupid reason it adds a space before (`class=" active"`). I don't know if that affects anything but that last little important detail of defaulting the checkbox under the active li class to checked doesn't work with any of my approaches.

All slightly similar posts I've searched for doesn't really answer my question. What am I missing here?!

Comment: It's almost certainly not the problem, but that code falls prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html): You need to declare `i`. By not declaring it, assigning to it creates a global variable automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if(listitem[i].className == " active")` is pretty easy to break (not having the space before `active`, having a space after it, having any other class before or after it). Instead, consider:

```
if (listitem[i].classList.contains("active"))
```

`classList.contains` looks to see if the element has the given class, regardless of any other classes it might have, or whether there is a space before or after the class name.

---

Separately, note that since your `input` is `type="radio"`¹ and has a `name`, only the *last* of those where you do `checked = true` will keep it, since a common `name` puts them in a group, and only one radio button can be checked at any given time.

(¹ typically we call those "radio buttons," not "checkboxes;" checkboxes are `type="checkbox"`)

Comment: How did I not think of that. We were thinking of the same thing (breaking out the class) but it seems I made it unnecessarily complicated by using that if-statement with a querySelector variable. That did work! Thanks a lot!